# Как задать статический размер кнопке JButton?

Tags: java, swing

Пытался задавать через `setPrefferedSize` - ничего не меняет. Пришла потом в голову мысль, что по размеру как-то подгоняется, раз Preffered. Потом уже решил вызывать два метода - `setMinimumSize` и `setMaximumSize`. Можно ли как-то проще и надежней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать метод `setSize`, если у вас не используется **Layout Manager**

Если вы используете **Layout Manager**, то размер компоненты будет вычисляться им на основе подсказок (hints), которые вы установите у компоненты. Подсказки это:

- `setPrefferedSize` - предпочитаемый размер
- `setMinimumSize` - минимальный размер
- `setMaximumSize` - максимальный размер

Следует учитывать, что **Layout Manager** учитываю подсказки не одинаково.

Comment: Разве можно добавлять элементы без Layout Manager'a?

Comment: да. вы добавляете элементы в контейнер.

Comment: @Андрей можно, делаете setLayout(null) а потом добавляете компоненты, делая им setBounds(x,y,w,h)